# How to make the target depend on lib file, but exclude it from $^ (VPATH involved)?

Tags: build, makefile, vpath

Imagine this structure:

```
root/
|
+-- include/
+-- src/
+-- build/
+-- lib/
+-- tests/
    |
    +-- common
    +-- test1
    +-- test2
    +-- test3
```

In `tests/`, the folder `common/` contains a couple of source files that generate data or read data from logged file etc, which are shared between all tests. Each test therefore has only one file; `main.c` (currently). The `Makefile` of each test looks like this:

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .o

TARGET := test
# OS dependent stuff omitted for brevity
CFLAGS += -I../../include -I../common
LDFLAGS += -L../../lib -lname

VPATH = ../common

.phony: all clean
all: $(TARGET)
clean:
    -$(RM) *.o $(TARGET)
# Other targets removed for brevity

OBJECTS := main.o io.o read_str.o
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) ../../lib/libname.a
    $(LD) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
main.o: main.c io.h $(wildcard ../../include/*.h)
```

At first I had the `common/` files copied in each test and everything was fine, but now that I put them in `common/` and used `VPATH`, I am facing an issue.

Let me explain a few lines:

```
main.o: main.c io.h $(wildcard ../../include/*.h)
               ^^^^
           VPATH correctly finds this file in common/

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) ../../lib/libname.a
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  If the library is rebuilt, the tests need to re-link

    $(LD) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)
                ^^^^^^^^^^
            I can't use $^ because that also includes ../../lib/libname.a
```

As you may have already guessed, since the `common/*.o` files are not in this folder, `$(LD)` fails to find them. On the other hand, `make`, given `VPATH = ../common` has no problem finding them. If I could remove `../../lib/libname.a`, then with `$^`, I could give the correct paths to the object files.

Removing the dependency to the lib file however, means that when I `make` at the top-level, the tests will not get updated if only the lib itself is being updated.

So, my question is, **how can I tell `make` there is a dependency to another file (a lib file) but it is not used in the command below it, given that the other dependencies are found using `VPATH`?**

I thought about removing the dependencies, and in the `Makefile` that builds `libname.a`, add a command after the library is made that tells the `Makefile`s of tests to remove their `TARGET`s:

```
lib/Makefile:

.SUFFIXES:

TARGET = libname.a
VPATH = ../build

.PHONY: all clean
all: $(TARGET)
clean:
        -$(RM) $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): list.o of.o my.o library.o files.o
        $(AR) $(TARGET) $^
        @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C ../tests remove_targets
```

This would force `$(LD)` to make them again. This solution however tends to make the `Makefile` relationships into a mess. The `Makefile` that builds the lib is unrelated to whether there are tests or not, and I prefer to keep them decoupled.

---

I build and test a lot, that is why I try to get the dependencies complete, so that `make` takes the minimum possible actions to correctly build everything. A solution that says, clean and rebuild every time is not an option.

I am also aware of [this syntax](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_4.html#SEC30), which could be used if I wanted to give the lib file directory to `gcc`, instead of using `-Lpath/to/lib -lname`. I am not sure however if that is a good idea (I mean, I always saw linking with `-L`, and I'm not sure if there is a disadvantage when directly giving the library file)

By the way, if I am doing something horribly wrong, or if I am making it too difficult for myself, please tell me how this should be done correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, my question is, **how can I tell make there is a dependency to another file (a lib file) but it is not used in the command below it, given that the other dependencies are found using VPATH?**

The question is "how can I make LIB a prerequisite but not be in the list of all prerequisites?"

This may not be the best answer, but should work, just filter it out of the list:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) ../../lib/libname.a
    $(LD) -o $@ $(filter-out ../../lib/libname.a,$^) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: That would work! I'll give the question a bit more time for other solutions, but I would accept this if nothing better showed up.

Comment: I think this (or something equivalent) is about the only option in this scenario.  In general, it would probably be simpler and neater to use `$(filter-out %.a,$^)`, though.