# Using -Lpath -lname options vs. providing the library file directly

Tags: gcc, linker, static-linking

Recently, I got into a problem with [linking and `VPATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078582/how-to-give-a-dependency-that-doesnt-appear-in-vpath-involved) with the side effect of this question.

Assume you are implementing a library and you want to link your tests with it. You have two options (that I know of):

- Using `-L` and `-l` options:

  ```
  gcc main.o -Lpath/to/lib -lname
  ```
- Giving the library file directly:

  ```
  gcc main.o path/to/lib/libname.a
  ```

My question is, given the fact that I am linking to my own library under implementation (and not one that is installed, and therefore placed in `/usr/lib` for example), **is there any advantage in choosing either method?**

Currently I use the first method, but the second method allows me to solve the problem I had with `VPATH`. I am particularly interested in knowing whether there are certain caveats with the second method, before making the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I can think of is that the first method allows the linker to choose a shared library if it exists. The second doesn't, because you explicitly name a `.a` static archive.

If you were using a shared library there is a difference: if the second form names a shared library without a soname the application would have a DT_NEEDED tag of `path/to/lib/libname.so`, but for the first form would have the tag with the value `libname.so`. (If the shared library has a soname that would be used for the DT_NEEDED tag however the path was specified.)

Comment: So probably the best idea would be to keep using `-L`, but filtering `$^` per your suggestion to my other question...